# Custom Library import reload in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am in a bit of a bind and looking for a solution to the following problem. I will present the code first.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Widget.py    ${FIRSTNAME}    ${LASTNAME}    WITH NAME    toy

*** Variables ***
${FIRSTNAME}    john
${LASTNAME}    doe

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    ${fullname}=    toy.get fullname
    Log To Console    ${fullname}
    Set Global Variable    ${FIRSTNAME}    jane
    ${fullname}=    toy.get fullname
    Log To Console    ${fullname}
```

In the code above, I am instantiating a library in `Settings` and creating an instance of the name `toy`.

After I use it, I am changing the `${FIRSTNAME}` variable value to `jane`.

After this line of code however, I would like that the instance `toy` refer to the new value of `${FIRSTNAME}` which is `jane`. However it still refers to the older value `john`.

Is there a way in Robot Framework to re-instantiate the library `Widget.py` with the new value of `${FIRSTNAME}` so that when I call `toy.get fullname` for the second time in the test case, it returns `jane doe` and NOT `john doe`?

OR

Is there a way to delete the `toy` instance and create a fresh instance in the same test case during runtime with the same name `toy` to maintain backward compatibility?

Comment: You can create your keyword that will update the FIRSTNAME in the library instance.